# plot selected columns using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape

I would like to plot multiple separate plots and so far I have the following code:

However, I don't want the final column from my dataset; it makes ggplot2 plot x-variable vs x-variable.

```
library(ggplot2)
require(reshape)
d <- read.table("C:/Users/trinh/Desktop/Book1.csv", header=F,sep=",",skip=24)
t<-c(0.25,1,2,3,4,6,8,10)
d2<-d2[,3:13] #removing unwanted columns
d2<-cbind(d2,t) #adding x-variable

df <- melt(d2,  id = 't')

ggplot(data=df, aes(y=value,x=t) +geom_point(shape=1) + 
geom_smooth(method='lm',se=F)+facet_grid(.~variable)
```

I tried adding

```
data=subset(df,df[,3:12])
```

but I don't think I am writing it correctly. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you could do it, using data(iris) as an example:

(i) plot with all variables

```
 df <- reshape2::melt(iris, id="Species")
 ggplot(df, aes(y=value, x=Species)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ variable)
```

[image]

(ii) plot without "Petal.Width"

```
 library(dplyr)
 df2 <- df %>% filter(!variable == "Petal.Width")
 ggplot(df2, aes(y=value, x=Species)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ variable)
```

[image]

Comment: hi, thanks for sharing your answer. would you happen to know if i can also remove two datapoints for the last or n number of plots? i.e. remove the last 2 y-variables, but keep them for the rest?

Comment: @Adam is there a way to do this without creating a new df?